# I couldn't import or use tdclient library

Tags: python, python-3.6

I got an error with this code:

```
from td.client import TDClient
```

Error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tdclient'
```

and I installed `tdclient` through the command line:

```
pip install td-client
```

and it was successfully installed.

Comment: Do you have multiple python installations? It is possible that you installed `td-client` into one environment but are running your python code in a separate python environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtual environments (venv), ensure you installed the module in the right venv.

If you are indeed using the right virtual env, or you're not using virtual environments at all, there may be a typo in the import statement.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i didnt understand what mean typo.

Comment: A simple mistake. Like, td.client instead of tdclient or something similar.